# Vazamento de conexões com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Meu sistema apresentava travamentos esporádicos e acabei descobrindo que isso acontecia devido a processos que abriam uma conexão mas, por conta de algum erro, não a fechavam (connection leak).

Solucionei envolvendo o código problemático em um `try/catch` e forçando o fechamento no `finally`

Minha pergunta é: Existe alguma forma de prevenir esse vazamento ou alguma configuração de timeout onde, após algum tempo de inatividade, a conexão seja devolvida/fechada?

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="udPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.com.xpto.etc</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="br.com.multitenant.SchemaResolver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="br.com.multitenant.MultiTenantProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="2"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.iddle_teste_period" value="70"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="15"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EntityManagerFactory**

```
public class FabricaEntityManager {

    private static FabricaEntityManager INSTANCE;
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private final static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(FabricaEntityManager.class);

    private FabricaEntityManager() {}

    public static FabricaEntityManager getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized (FabricaEntityManager.class) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE = new FabricaEntityManager();
                        log.debug("Nova Fabrica");
                    }
                }
            }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        if (emf==null){
            emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("udonlinePU");
            log.debug("Create EMF");
        }
        return emf;
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de transação**

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if (manager == null || !manager.isOpen()) {
            manager=FabricaEntityManager.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            log.debug(">> CreateEntityManager");
        }
        return manager;
    }
public List<Despesa> getByAll(){
        Query qry=getEntityManager().createQuery("select d from Despesa d ");
        List<Despesa> rs = qry.getResultList();
        getEntityManager().close();
        return rs;
    }
```

Comment: Boa tarde você poderia trabalhar com JPA + Hibernate e deixar o contender gerenciar sua conexões.

Comment: Você quer dizer para criar o pool no Tomcat e deixá-lo gerenciar as conexões? Se for isso, veja que estou trabalhando com Multitenant / multi schema. Como eu faria isso com o pool do Tomcat?

Comment: Abrir e fechar as conexões em cada operação, diminui a performance. Utilize uma API para gerenciar seu pool.

Answer (score 1):

O jeito correto é utilizar alguma solução global para controle de transação. Eu consigo me lembrar de 3 agora:

1. Utilizar o padrão OpenSessionInView: Desse modo você terá um FilterWeb que ao receber a requisição abriria uma conexão, e ao terminar a fecharia. Isso seria feito com o try/finally que vc criou para solucionar o outro problema.
2. Com EJB - Se você estiver utilizando um servidor que tenha EJB, deixe que o EJB tome conta da transação por você.
3. Com Spring - Utilize o Spring e deixe-o controlar a transação para você.

Se você não utilizar um framework/padrão que controle a transação você terá que fazer try/finally em todos seus métodos.

OBS.: pool de conexão só serve para te dar a conexão, e nada mais. 
OBS2.: Honestamente nunca vi uma configuração que matasse determinada conexão que está ativa a X tempo. Esse errp geralmente é má prática de progamação.

Comment: Hoje eu utilizo um EntityManagerFactory (classe singleton FabricaEntityManager) que cria as instâncias de EntityManager que uso para lidar com as transações do database... são estes entityManagers que são abertos e fechados a todo momento. Essa factory não deveria fazer este controle? Ou seja, reutilizar as conexões e abrir quando necessário?

Comment: Você tem que informar a ela que o request acabou de algum modo, e só assim ela poderia fechar a conexão. Mas... honestamente? Factory deve só criar e não gerenciar uma conexão.

Comment: Sim, a factory só cria o entitymanager... quem solicita/fecha são os DAOs. O que me despertou a curiosidade é saber se este processo que estou fazendo é correto, ou seja, o DAO solicitar o entityManager ao factory e depois fechar. Será que isso pode ser melhorado? Não é muito custoso?

Comment: Isso vai depender de como foi arquitetado o sistema. Se você isolar toda a questão da conexão dentro do DAO, eu não vou dizer que esta errado. Mas vou dizer que você terá muito trabalho para finalizar as conexões. Em toda chamada vai ter que ter um try/finally. Aos meus olhos podem ser finalizados utilizando alguma abordagem descrita acima. Agora a relação custo/benefício é algo muito particular da gerência ver isso e apoiar. (: